# ¿Donde ubicar la licencias que usa mi App?

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría saber si uso una canción de `free commercial use` y dice que tengo que mencionar al autor, dónde tengo que hacerlo para que no me baneen.

También si sabéis de páginas donde no haya copy sin nombrar (es un consejo que admito pues he buscado y he encontrado algunas pero no son de calidad).

Comment: Si tienes una vista "About this" en el apartado licencias, seria lo apropiado

Answer (score 1):

puedes nombrarlo en un sector de la aplicacion con un acerca de (seria lo optimo).. o bien poner un txt en los archivos de programacion, donde menciones los autores, recuerda que cada licensia tiene su cosa particular, es importante saber el tipo de licencia que usas para saber en que convierte a tu codigo.. por ejemplo si usas codigo con licencia GPL te obliga a que tu codigo sea codigo abierto